# How do you delete CloudWatch Log Group from the AWS Console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I've been trying to delete it, but it keeps showing back up

Comment: Probably something is generating it.

Comment: I don't think so @Marcin

Comment: What is the Log Group called?

Comment: Use `aws logs describe-log-groups` to see when the log group was created, maybe there are even more introspection tools so you can see who created it. Maybe using CloudTrail.